# Ubuntu Touch - Dekko crashes when I try to open it

Tags: ubuntu-touch, email-client

Over the last few days, I have added two more gmail email accounts to my Dekko client. It already had one, so in total, now three. Last night on adding the third account. The details were all taken OK and then it froze, so I closed it down and tried to start it up again.

Now when I try to open Dekko email, it brings up the menu dropdown list on the left hand side of the screen and then closes. It happens like this all the time. Reboot and even praying to the gods does not help. When I see the menu, I can see that the third account in the Accounts section, but it is not in the top section where my other two accounts are.

I have the same set up for my tablet and that works fine, it is just on the E5 phone where it continually crashes.

Is this a known issue or does anyone know of a fix for this?

Comment: A while ago I had filed https://bugs.launchpad.net/dekko/+bug/1568350 which speaks about dekko crashing on start. My problem with searching for the cause was in the absence of any useful information in any logs.  So far no developer has commented on that bug.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Stephan, it sure does sound lit it is the same issue. I hope that you do not mind, but I have added your bug id, to mine. It is not good that no developers have got back to you. Hopefully, both our bugs will get this fixed.

Comment: I still have not had any word on the defect logged. I would of thought that someone would of looked at it by now.

Comment: From looking at the comments in bug/1568350, it would appear that the issue may be resolved in the new build. I look forward to receiving the new build and indeed seeing if this will be fixed.

Comment: You may also want to check the debug build I posted on https://bugs.launchpad.net/dekko/+bug/1577690/ - it's a bit of a hackish fix, but seems to work with offline settings/start offline set to on.

Comment: I noticed that this also happens when I open my Dekko email client when I have no internet connection. The side menu will open and then in a few seconds the app will close. The good thing is that I have not had this issue again when connected to the net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the problem comes when "Email settings/Offline settings/Start offline" is set to "ON".

Comment: thanks for this, it appears to of fixed the issue. I have been using my emails now for 2 days and it has not crashed. Hopefully, the fix for the bug will be out soon.

Answer (score 3):

Try to backup these folders:

```
~/.local/share/dekko.dekkoproject/
~/.config/dekko.dekkoproject/
~/.cache/dekko.dekkoproject/
```

Then delete them. All your account data will be cleared. Add the accounts again (perhaps creating a new backup after adding the second account would be wise). If the problem persists, try varying different things like the order in which you add the accounts so that you would know what makes Dekko crash: the number of accounts or the particular account. It wouldn't help you, but it might be useful for the developers when they will fix this bug. You might be able to contact them by IRC (#dekko on Freenode), but I believe that it should be done after submitting a bug to [their bugtracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dekko).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have file manager but I cannot find the files that you have mentioned above. Can you add the full path please and then I will try and locate them again.

Comment: The files or folders starting with dot are hidden, you'll have to turn on displaying hidden files in your file manager. All these hidden folders are located in your home folder. If you've got a terminal emulator you can do it all there with command mv which will move the files to the destination you need (for backup) and command rm for deleting the folders after unsuccessful tries.

Comment: That worked a treat, thank you for the answer. All three accounts are showing up on my Dekko email on my phone now.

Comment: Unfortunately, today when I clicked on my Dekko email client icon, the same issue came back. So I have the option of removing all the files again and adding the accounts again. Or just un-installing it all together and leaving it, using the GMail client instead. I think this may be the way to go until it is usable. With all the other things that need sorting out on the phone, I just really do not need the haste.

Comment: I have reported this under the following bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/dekko/+bug/1576956

Answer (score 0):

Here's a "bump" for a bq Aquaris M10 FHD running Ubuntu 15.04(r3) from UBPorts.

It looks to me like it's still a problem with loading offline.

***Don't delete your configuration***

At the bottom of ~/.config/dekko.dekkoproject/dekko.dekkoproject.conf
there's a [global] section and when I set 
imap.enable=true
imap.offline=false

dekko started again.

***Don't forget to make a copy of the original before you edit it***